# Yocto: Image creation date is older than the original creation date

Tags: linux, yocto, yocto-recipe

Currently I am working with stm32mp1 board and developing Yocto image for the Kirkstone version. I have the following build configuration for the baord.

```
   Build Configuration:
   BB_VERSION           = "2.0.0"
   BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
   NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"
   TARGET_SYS           = "arm-emt_eglfs-linux-gnueabi"
   MACHINE              = "emsbc-argon"
   DISTRO               = "emt-eglfs"
   DISTRO_VERSION       = "1.3"
   TUNE_FEATURES        = "arm vfp cortexa7 neon vfpv4 thumb callconvention-hard"
   TARGET_FPU           = "hard"
   DISTRO_CODENAME      = "kirkstone"
   ACCEPT_EULA_emsbc-argon = "1"
   GCCVERSION           = "11.%"
   PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel = "linux-stm32mp-argon"
   meta-emtrion-emsbc-argon = "HEAD:7c4912ff0cecc10281ca52a18402d0a29d9ad6ec"
   meta-emtrion         = "HEAD:254f385f1d5b8deb0723a0dc4fdb996dd64661b1"  
   meta                 = "HEAD:f7766da462905ec67bf549d46b8017be36cd5b2a"
   meta-oe              
   meta-initramfs       
   meta-multimedia      
   meta-python          
   meta-networking      
   meta-webserver       
   meta-filesystems     
   meta-perl            = "HEAD:05dcac98473402d87e0af73bbc2c5a6a840abe93"
   meta-qt5             = "HEAD:5b71df60e523423b9df6793de9387f87a149ac42"
   meta-st-stm32mp      = "HEAD:ca501bd7dbe023682903ceedddaacd940b0898f4"
   meta-st-openstlinux  = "HEAD:cb736b403d0fef2a02390695613b6b4bb13ca1b7"
   meta-gnome           
   meta-xfce            = "HEAD:05dcac98473402d87e0af73bbc2c5a6a840abe93"
```

After compiling the image, I formatted my sd card and running that image via sd card. When I am in Linux kernel, and when I give the command ***uname -a***, I get board specification with the image creation date. But the image creation date is 2 years old, though I created image just last week. What could be the reason? The image creation date should be 1 week old.

Also I created the image based on the vendor's recipe. Which means I did not create my own device tree and kernel. I just adopt their file and compiled the image using bitbake command. If anyone can give me any link, that would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most probably what you see is the date of last commit in your kernel (vendors tend to think that kernel is like fine wine: the older the better). uname will show a "system version", that usually includes a date also. This comes from libc, which generally just returns some kind of kernel version string that it manages to parse.